# Can ECSlidingViewController2 been used with both a left and right bar button?

Tags: ios, ecslidingviewcontroller, ecslidingviewcontroller-2

Does anyone know if ECSlidingViewController2 can be used with both a left and a right UIBarButtonItem at the same time? Each of the examples only show a single button used on the left of the navigation bar.

https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

For future reference, an example showing ECSlidingViewController2 using both a left and right UIBarButtonItem at the same time can now be found at:

https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController/tree/master/Examples/LayoutDemo

Comment: This question is not about "general computing". Bad close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The LayoutDemo had a left and right button.

Answer (score 0):

`ECSlidingViewController` uses a pan gesture recognizer to slide view controllers. It should work with any combination of left and right bar button items.